# How would a sea turtle end up on its back?

Tags: animal-behaviour, sea, turtles

There is a [video](https://i.imgur.com/4A1sMZg.gifv) going round of two guys flipping a sea turtle that had ended up on its back so it could get back into the water.

How would a **sea turtle end up on its back in the first place** (it sure doesn't seem that the turtle would do that on purpose)?

Comment: A really, really good friend told it an incredibly hilarious joke - it just couldn't stop from rolling over laughing. As truly good friends do, they found the situation so funny they needed to walk away to observe from a distance how the situation would evolve.

Comment: A wave could have tipped it when the tide was higher.

Comment: @imsodin It probably started with "Hold my seaweed and watch this!"

Comment: And if you're not helping the turtle flip back over, [you might be a replicant](https://youtu.be/Umc9ezAyJv0?t=71).

Answer (score 24):

There are a few possibilities:

**Other Turtles**

[This site](https://animals.mom.me/mean-turtle-keeps-flipping-over-11385.html) about pet turtles mentions the possibility that turtles fighting over a mate (or actually mating) may end up on their backs.

> When breeding season comes around, adult male turtles might start
>   fighting over the females. A stronger male might flip a weaker one
>   over. Male turtles might also harass female turtles, attempting to
>   breed. Females can become flipped over and injured. Male turtles can
>   also fall onto their backs after mating.

**Illness**

As Sue says in the comments (and backed up [here](https://animals.mom.me/mean-turtle-keeps-flipping-over-11385.html)) fluid in the lungs due to respiratory illness may cause them to tip if they're submerged. A flipped turtle could then be washed ashore and remain upside down.

This brings me to another possibility:

**Waves**

As waves come to shore, the water molecules in those waves are spinning in a circular motion. With large waves, this is often enough to flip things over (surfboards and people on surfboards are the most common examples).

The part of the object closest to the approaching wave gets lifted first and thrown over, if the wave is steep enough. Breaking waves are exactly this phenomenon--the top of the wave is steep enough that the circularly moving water gets "thrown" forward and over itself. Waves usually break near shore--hence the turtle on the beach.

Also, it's worth noting that there's no reason the turtle would only flip 180 degrees. In all likelihood, half the turtles landing on the beach are right side up, and they just walk (?) away.

**People**

In the interest of being exhaustive about the possibilities, I want to mention that there are people who may think it's funny to flip a turtle on its back. I hope that wasn't the case here, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Hi! This is interesting! Do you have a source that waves are causal? If so, would you add it, so I can learn more?  You clearly said "most likely" so I don't think you're misleading. It could be 100% true but my preliminary scientific research about doesn't say it! I hope I haven't bothered you! I'd just appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Comment: Part of my interest is that we had a pet aquatic turtle in an aquarium who got pneumonia. The heavy fluid in one of his lungs caused him to tip. We gave IV fluids and other treatments but he passed away. I don't know if this happens with larger aquatic species.

Comment: Very good points. In short: I don't have a source, but I think it's a possible explanation. Perhaps not most likely though! I've edited to include other potential reasons, with citations (and hopefully enough credit to you!).

Comment: This is great, thanks! Thanks for the extra work! I didn't need credit at all, you're very kind!!

Comment: On reddit they were mentioning that poacers might do it to immobolize the turtles

Comment: Note that "turtles fighting" is only true for terrestial turtles (most commonly known as tortoises) and some marshland species that spend time out of water. Most terrapins fight by biting and scratching (no ramming involved and its mostly underwater) and male sea-turtles never leave the water so would not suffer from being flipped over. My guess in this case is a combination of illness and being caught in the surf.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the reasons given in [@John Hughes answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/22538/16499), **Predators** may be another cause.

This [SeaWorld Parks & Entertainment page](https://seaworld.org/animals/all-about/sea-turtles/longevity/) on the longevity and causes of death of sea turtles lists *tiger sharks* and *killer whales* (*orcas*) as the main predators of adult turtles.

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcABumZSDXY) (also featured, with additional notes, in [this LiveScience.com article](https://www.livescience.com/63622-orca-spins-sea-turtle.html)) shows an orca "playing" with a sea turtle, and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USaqTbWbeII) shows one being repeatedly tossed into the air. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUgq-ffRJFw) shows a tiger shark and a turtle in very shallow water (with the turtle getting it's own back at 01:55).

Although none of the videos actually show a turtle being beached (and I haven't found one that does), the tiger shark video is in very shallow water, and killer whales are known to prey right up to (and on to!) beaches (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtF3FPyRVIw) of one attacking seals that are on the beach), so it certainly seems possible that either predator could – presumably accidentally – flip a turtle from the shallows to the beach and for the turtle to land on its back.

[image: Sea Turtle tossed by Killer Whale]

<sup>*Source: partial screen-grab from [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USaqTbWbeII](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USaqTbWbeII_)*</sup>

[image: Killer Whale attacking seals on beach]

<sup>*Source: partial screen-grab from [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtF3FPyRVIw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtF3FPyRVIw_)*</sup>

[image: Turtle attacking tiger shark]

<sup>*Source: partial screen-grab from [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUgq-ffRJFw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUgq-ffRJFw_)*</sup>

Comment: "_This SeaWorld Parks & Entertainment page on the longevity and causes of death of sea turtles lists tiger sharks and killer whales (orcas) as the main prey of adult turtles._" - Although the thought of a turtle hunting a killer whale is amusing, I'm pretty sure you meant to write _predator_ instead of _prey_.

Comment: Thanks - fixed. I think I was thinking "_main [creatures that] prey **on** adult turtles_" but have switched to predator for clarity.